# Galaxy S2 SPH-D710 Exchange ActiveSync Settings & Mail Disappear? 4.0.4 Sprint

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, exchange, active-sync

I have a user with a Samsung Galaxy S2, 4.0.4 on Sprint. She said she took her son to senior photos and when she got back to her truck with her phone sitting on the console, all the Exchange Server settings for ActiveSync disappeared including her e-mails. She came into my office and we input the Exchange settings for company e-mail and was able to get her phone synced up again, but this is like the second time it has happened in about a month or so, any ideas? Thanks!